# Delphi ClientDataSet - How to add new data fields to existing dataset?

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I'm having trouble working out how to add new data fields to an old dataset file. For example, an old dataset might have an ID field only. Later on we decide we need an ISACTIVE field. I want to reopen my ID-only data and then resave it with ISACTIVE values added. For example:

```
CDS := TClientDataset.Create(nil);
with TIntegerField.Create(CDS) do
begin
  FieldName := 'ID';
  FieldKind := fkData;
  DataSet := CDS;
end;
CDS.CreateDataSet;

CDS.Close;
with TBooleanField.Create(CDS) do
begin
  FieldName := 'ISACTIVE';
  FieldKind := fkData;
  DataSet := CDS;
end;
CDS.Open; // <--Raises EDatabaseError with message 'Field 'ISACTIVE' not found'.
```

I had a look for similar questions, the closest I found was one that concerned adding new calculated fields to a dataset only. This method above works fine for adding a calculated field.

At the moment the only (messy) solution I can think of is to load the ID-only data into a temporary dataset, then create a new dataset with ID and ISACTIVE fields defined, then loop through the ID-only dataset and copy the records across to the new dataset.

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293186/delphi-change-fields-definitions-of-a-tclientdataset-that-has-data

Comment: hmm, yep in a way. It is quite an oddly posed question I think?! Anyways, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21295035/6620329 describes what I referred to as "messy" solution at the end of my question. Maybe that is the only option available to me though (bar MartynA's suggestion of editing the text file on disk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this.

If you have a CDS with an Integer ID Field and a String 80 Name field, and you save the dataset to XML, as in

```
AFileName := 'C:\Temp\CDSData.Xml';
CDS1.SaveToFile(AFileName, dfXML);
```

the resulting XML file will look like this (for D7)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>  
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
  <METADATA>
    <FIELDS>
      <FIELD attrname="ID" fieldtype="i4"/>
      <FIELD attrname="Name" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="80"/>
    </FIELDS><PARAMS CHANGE_LOG="1 0 4"/>
  </METADATA>
  <ROWDATA>
    <ROW RowState="4" ID="1" Name="one"/>
  </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

You can then use MSXML or your favourite XML processor to make the trivial change to add additional `FIELD` node(s) to the `METADATA` defining the `CCDS`'s datapacket, to add the extra field(s).  You then reload the CDS from the XML.  The added field(s) values will be NULL of course and for this technique to work, you must not have persistent TFields defined on the CDS at the time you reload it from the saved XML.

Example code:

```
procedure TForm1.CopyWithAddedFields;
var
  SS : TStringStream;
  XMLDoc : IXmlDomDocument;
  FieldsNode : IXmlDomNode;
  FieldElement : IXmlDomElement;
begin
  SS := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    //  Save the CDS's current contents in XML format, close it and clear any presistent fields
    CDS1.SaveToStream(SS, dfXML);
    CDS1.Close;
    CDS1.Fields.Clear;

    //  Next create an XML Document object and load the saved dataset into it
    XMLDoc := CoDomDocument.Create;
    XMLDoc.LoadXML(SS.DataString);

    //  Find the FIELDS node and add a new FIELD node to it       
    FieldsNode := XMLDoc.selectSingleNode('/DATAPACKET/METADATA/FIELDS');
    FieldElement := XMLDoc.createElement('FIELD');
    FieldElement.SetAttribute('attrname', 'Active');
    FieldElement.SetAttribute('fieldtype', 'boolean');
    FieldsNode.appendChild(FieldElement);

    // Save the XML to the stream
    SS.Size := 0;
    SS.WriteString(XmlDoc.xml);
    SS.Position := 0;

    //  Reload the ClientDataset
    CDS1.LoadFromStream(SS);
  finally
    XMLDoc.Free;
    SS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Obviously, you could load the modified XML into a different CDS instead if you wanted to.

Of course, you could even add the extra `FIELD` nodes to the XML just by loading it into a TStringList if you were prepared to do a certain amount of string-twiddling yourself.

Fwiw, I stumbled upon this ruse when trying to modify the XML of a CDS to include extra information for each `ROW` node in the XML file;  it turned out that the `LoadFromFile` & `LoadFromStream` processes were completely oblivious to the information I added.

Comment: It is a valid answer, and actually easier to implement than I imagined. However I don't really see an advantage to this approach over the "messy" solution I described above.

Comment: Each to his own, I guess.  The reason I prefer this approach myself is that it you rewrite it as a "toolbox" routine, then all you need supply by way of input is a bit of XML defining the fields to be added (and optionally initial field values).

Comment: Nice! The advantage of this approach is that it doesn't require extra ClientDataSet to copy data into.

Answer (score -1):

Hm, what wrong with calculated fields? Could you please explain why you do not want to use them?

One extra hint: Have you tried InternalCalc (`FieldKind = fkInternalCalc`). AFAIK it should behave similar to data field (it's values are stored within the dataset record)

PS and there is no need to reload data (close and reopen dataset) when you adding a calculated field

Comment: This is the objective: [link](http://i.imgur.com/4mLIlil.png).
In other words, add new data (new fields) to previously saved dataset. InternalCalc or not makes no difference, neither is saved to disk when you call SaveToFile. Why don't I want to use calculated field? It is about backwards compatibility. There are many saved "files" in the wild with old structure. I need to add new properties to the old files when a user opens and re-saves it. TClientDataSet is not making that task easy!

Comment: And a side note: Adding a new InternalCalc field to an open TClientDataSet certainly does cause  `EDatabaseError with message 'Cannot perform this operation on an open dataset'.`